# How would I raise a number to a power in Modelica?

Tags: system-modeler

This is a very basic question that I cannot seem to find a solution to.

The following line throws an error in Modelica:

```
parameter  Real    chargeDensity(unit = "C/m")=10^-10;
```

The error is:

```
File "<interactive>", line 6, column 90, after '^' and before '-':
Syntax error: At this point, a primary expression is expected, e.g., a value literal, a component reference, or a function call.
```

The only way I have found to do this is:

```
parameter  Real    chargeDensity(unit = "C/m")=1/10^10
```

Is there a power function or operator in Modelica that accepts a negative exponent?  Would I have to use an `if` clause to check the sign of an exponent variable?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to the programming language Mathematica.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau SystemModeler questions were voted to be on-topic here: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/are-questions-about-systemmodeler-on-topic , and since Modelica is the underlying language for SystemModeler, this should be on-topic as well.

Comment: @MalteLenz Is there any indication that SystemModeler was being used here?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau As a SystemModeler developer, I recognize the error message ;). But otherwise, no there isn't. Also as a SystemModeler developer, I don't think its my place to decide whether this is on-topic or not. I'll stand aside now and let the rest of the community make such decisions.

Comment: @MalteLenz SystemModeler questions are of course fair game. This one is well disguised though.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is:

```
parameter  Real    chargeDensity(unit = "C/m")=10^(-10.0);
```

An error is produced for negative exponents if the parenthesis are omitted.